# MSI Motherboard won't boot from perfectly good bootable CDs

Tags: boot, motherboard

The issue is with a brand new 890FXA-GD65 motherboard, but likely affects other recent MSI models. When you place a good bootable CD in a working CD drive and attempt to boot it, it tries to load the CD then fails saying its not a valid boot disk.

Trying different cd/dvd drives that are known good and bootable in other machines doesn't fix the problem. Trying other disks about 10 in my case, all of which are good bootable disks on other machines, does not resolve the problem- only 1 in 10 disks would work.

Note: I just figured out the solution to this problem prior to posting this, but I'm going to post it anyway to save the next person with this problem the agony. I didn't see this answer on other questions and it appears to be motherboard specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of frustration and agony, it appears that this motherboard has its own built in bootloader that's set as the first boot device by default. This boot loader loads, then it attempts to load from the CD drive. It appears to the user that the motherboard is attempting a boot from the CD as you expect, so there is no reason to suspect that CD was not in the list of bootable devices. The solution is to change the boot order from:

1. Unnecessary MSI Bootloader
2. Hard Drive
3. CD

To

1. Hard Drive
2. CD
3. Disabled

I have no idea why they decided they needed to have a built in boot device that boots CDs when the motherboard already does it (better), but booting from the CD directly instead of using their default bootloader allows bootable CDs to load properly.